# Validate form with jQuery in different section

Tags: jquery, validation

I have been thinking how to display the validation messages into different sections of the form. I have an online quotation with single html form. I have put them into different section to ease the user enter the information based on the categories.

I have divided the form for example into the Customer Contact Details, Consultants Details, Customer Credit Card Details, Air Ticket Sections. Please note that the actual form is not as simple as this one.
I want to do a jQuery validation on this form. The problem is I want to separate the validation messages base on its category. I do not want mix the validation messages into one. This will confuse the consultants, as this form is a fully dynamic form, and it can be consist for more than 100 fields for just only single quotation.

So, for Customer Contact Details, the validation messages will only notify the user anything that is associated with the Customer Contact Details.  Anything that is not valid, the message will be displayed next to the associated field. Same thing for Consultant Details and Customer Credit Card Details.

However, it is different with Air Ticket Sections, where bunch of information are placed in a table. With the table format, the validation messages cannot be displayed next to the field. So, I am thinking to use jQuery errorLableContainer to display the messages.

At this point of time, I only can think to use different html form. However, I do not want to do this. I want to keep it with single html form. Or, I can use jQuery groups, where I haven't done the testing to use jQuery groups.

Anyone has any better idea to solve this validation messages? Any thought would be appreciated. I am sure, someone out there are also having the same issues.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery.validate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) lets you specify what you want the error message to be per input field, and since jQuery uses CSS so nicely you can style individual error messages by selecting each specific error message.

You'll have to include your code to get more specific help, but here is an example of jQuery validation that returns specific error messages:

```
$("your_form").validate({
            rules: {
                FIELD1: { required: true },
                FIELD2: { required: true },
                FIELD3: { required: true }
            },
            messages: {
                FIELD1: "Error message 1",
                FIELD2: "Error message 2",
                FIELD3: "Error message 3"
            },
            success: function(label) {
                label.addClass('valid');
            },
            error: function(submit) {
                return false;
            }
```

Note that "FIELD1" "FIELD2" and so on the *label* names as well as ids for the each input element (I'm not sure whether this plugin selects by id or label name, sorry).

Then, you'd style the error messages by using something like `label[for="FIELD1"].error` to select each error message (beware, IE7 and below do some weird stuff with this CSS notation).